# PUT/POST not working in self-hosted WCF REST configuration

Tags: wcf, rest, config, put

I have a self-hosted server (Windows service) that is supporting both SOAP/RPC (this may go away in the future) and REST. The RESTful GETs are working as expected, but PUT/POST are giving a 405 error (Method Not Supported). I'm pretty sure this is a configuration issue with my app.config, but I'm pretty new to this and am not sure what to try.

Below is my config file. Any help would be *greately* appreciated...

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <!-- bindings -->
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name ="soapBinding">
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="webBinding" />
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <!-- behaviors -->
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <!-- plain old XML -->
        <behavior name="poxBehavior">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
        <!-- JSON -->
        <behavior name="jsonBehavior">
          <enableWebScript  />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="DSServerBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <!-- services -->
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="DSServerBehavior" name="dsServer.DSServer">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8000/DecisionSupportServer" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint address="soap" 
                  binding="basicHttpBinding" 
                  bindingConfiguration="soapBinding" 
                  contract="dsServer.IDSServer" />
        <endpoint address="mex" 
                  binding="mexHttpBinding" 
                  contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <endpoint address="rest"
                  binding="webHttpBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration="webBinding"
                  behaviorConfiguration="poxBehavior"
                  contract="dsServer.IDSServer" />
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Ack. The XML configuration was elided off the posting. I'll have to figure out how to attach it.

Comment: @Allan: you just need to highlight your XML (or code) and then click on the "code" button (010 101) on the editor toolbar - or press Ctrl-K on your keyboard - to format it nicely

Comment: Ah! Thanks for fixing the post format.

Comment: I'll add that the interface is using correct attributes, as in:

[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "encryptions/{plain}")]
[OperationContract]
String Encrypt (String plain);

Comment: Do you actually have an attribute that says  [WebInvoke(Method = "PUT"... on your service contract?

Comment: Yep, I do. I also have other methods that have WebGet(). They work fine. By the way, I have one interface and half the methods are for SOAP/RPC and the other half are WebGet/WebInvoke.

Comment: Strange.  I have a self hosted WCF service that uses the non-standard verb "PATCH" and it works fine.  Have you tried testing it from a Console App?

Comment: I tried earlier using CURL to POST to it. I just went back and tried again and it appeared to work. I'll get to the bottom of this and report back.

Comment: Well. This is embarassing. It all appears to be working, even being driven from a Perl client. Thanks for having me double-check the console interface. I would have spun my wheels a bit more. I'd just chalk this one up to User Error.

Answer (score 0):

I double-checked this using CURL and made a small change to my client. This was straight User Error. :(